# jQuery toggleClass() Not Toggling Class After The First Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please disregard the stuff below the asterisks. I've added a fiddle since the snippets I provided weren't very useful then I first posted this.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erobertwald/gc0fod1b/57/

When I click on 'Menu 1', the modal appears, and the content also appears. When I click the the modal anywhere around the panel the modal disappears and I'm assuming the nested content also disappears because when I click on 'Menu 1' again, the modal appears but the nested content does not. (Not sure why, but in the fiddle, the 'X' (close) button doesn't work at the moment.) - Edit: Would have helped if I had the right ID!)

Trying to figure out what's causing the problem.

************************* Original Post ******************************

I've added these events to an element using the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#site-header > div:nth-child(1)', toggleGalleriesModal);
$(document).on('click', '#modal-close-button', toggleModal);
$(document).on('click', '#modal-backdrop', toggleModal);
```

Which fires this function every time:

```
function toggleGalleriesModal(){
    var content = $('<div id="galleries-modal-content">');
    toggleModal('Galleries', content);
}
```

in the toggleModal() function, I'm toggling the visibility of the modal itself, and then content nested inside it:

```
function toggleModal(label, content){
    window.event.stopPropagation();
    if(content != null) currentModalContent = content;
    currentModalContent.toggleClass('active');
    $('#modal').toggleClass('visible');
}
```

When I click on the `#site-header > div:nth-child(1)` element, the modal appears, and the content also appears. When I click either `#modal-close-button` or `#modal-backdrop` the modal disappears and I'm assuming the nested content also disappears because when I click on `#site-header > div:nth-child(1)` again, the modal appears but the nested content does not.

Really stumped here. I've been chasing my tail on this and looking online but haven't figured out or found a solution.

Comment: Are you able to provide us with a working snippet?

Comment: To toggle modal visibility just use $('#modal').modal('hide') or $('#modal').modal('toggle');

Comment: The handlers for `#modal-close-button` and `#modal-backdrop` aren't passing the `label` and `content` arguments to `toggleModal()`.

Comment: `window.event.` is bad code, that is not how modern browsers work.

Comment: I also don't understand what you're doing with the `content` parameter. It's a newly-created DOM element, but you never add it to the DOM anywhere.

Comment: Right, `window.event` doesn't exist in Firefox. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636400/event-equivalent-in-firefox

Comment: What is `currentModalContent`?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#modal-close-button', toggleModal);` calls `toggleModal` and it will not match `toggleModal(label, content){`

Comment: Here's the fiddle with the rest of the blanks filled in: https://jsfiddle.net/erobertwald/gc0fod1b/40/. I should have remembered that code excerpts aren't helpful. Sorry. It's been a while.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It was one of those cases of something staring me straight in the face...

In the JS, I had this:

```
   var content = $('<div id="galleries-modal-content">');
   if ($('#galleries-modal-content').length == 0) {
       // code to create the galleries-modal-content
   }
```

Which created the element each time and, big shock: wiped out its contents each time.

So I changed this around to:

```
var content;
if($('#galleries-modal-content').length == 0){
    content = $('<div id="galleries-modal-content">');
    // code to create the galleries-modal-content
}
```

And added an else:

```
}
    // code to create the galleries-modal-content
}else{
    content = $('#galleries-modal-content');
}
```

That did the trick.